# Blazor InputSelect OnChange trigger UI Update

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I am not quite sure if I am asking the right question.  I assume other people have had this issue.

I built my own Blazor Grid component.  I am using an  bound to a property.

I have a function to load my grid.  I changed my bound property to a full getter,setter.  In the setter, I call my function to load the grid.  This works fast and easy in pretty much all instances.  But, I have one grid that when binding it will take a few extra seconds to complete.

The problem:  I can't seem to figure out how to get my waiting spinner component to show when loading my grid.

Example Blazor Markup:

```
    @if (dataGrid == null)
    {
        <hr />
        <BitcoSpinner></BitcoSpinner>
    }
    else
    {
        <BitcoGrid TheGrid="dataGrid"></BitcoGrid>
    }
```

Here is my property and GridLoading:

```
private string selectedGroup1 = "";
public string selectedGroup
{
    get => selectedGroup1;
    set
    {
        selectedGroup1 = value;
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

private void LoadGrid()
{
    dataGrid = null;

    PT_Grid_Admin ptGrid = new PT_Grid_Admin(permitTraxLibrary, gridParams);
    dataGrid = ptGrid.ADMIN_FeeList(feeList.Fee_Key, selectedGroup);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `LoadGrid` method asynchronously. Therefore, at the beginning of the program, when the data grid value is set, your spinner will be displayed until the data grid value is not received. Then, after receiving the data grid value, the `else part` of the condition will be executed and its value will be displayed to the user.

It may not take much time to receive information from the DB in local mode, so the following code can be used to simulate the delay:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

In general, I think that if your code changes like this, you can see the spinner.

```
private string selectedGroup1 = "";
public string selectedGroup
{
get => selectedGroup1;
set
{
    selectedGroup1 = value;
    LoadGrid();
}
}

private async Task LoadGrid()
{
    dataGrid = null;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    .
    .

}
```

Of course, it is better to load the `datagrid` in `OnInitializedAsync` method. For more info you can refer to [this link](https://medium.com/@kajepratik/how-to-display-loading-indicator-while-blazor-component-is-loading-353417d067d0).